# What's the best practice for instance renderering?

Tags: opengl

I've created a renderer that works but I feel I can improve it. The biggest problem that I see right now is data duplication. Right now its batching all the objects into a VBO but this can lead to redundant data. What I thought of was having one VBO to store all the vertices of my models (only one of each) and because I'm using `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` I can create instances of each of these models by putting them in their own draw command. What I thought of doing was then having another VBO to store per-instance data (model matrix, color, etc.) and then have an instance array and pass it in as an attribute using `glVertexAttribDivisor`. Is this way ok?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "OK"? It's not clear what the end-goal of this process is. Also: "*this can lead to redundant data*" How does that create redundant data?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Well if i have 2 objects that use the same vertices and put them in the VBO that's redundant data. And when I say ok, I mean if this is the right way of doing things

Comment: "*Well if i have 2 objects that use the same vertices and put them in the VBO that's redundant data.*" If you have "two objects that use the same vertices", why would you put them in the same buffer twice? Why would you not simply render using the same source vertex data? I mean, would you load the same texture twice if two different "objects" use it? "*if this is the right way of doing things*" There is no "right way." There are plenty of wrong ways, but no "right way". What is "right" depends on what your goals are.